# Iteration through shapefile rows is taking too long

Tags: r, leaflet, iteration, if-else, for-loop

I'am using a shapefile with leaflet in r, where i am iterating through each row of that shapefile with a for loop and then i run an if statement on each of the rows as it iterates through the shapefile. My problem is that when I run it, it takes ages to iterate through and show the results. Is there any way to speed up my code?

R code:

```
# loop through each row of shapefile and run if statement on each row.
for(i in 1:nrow(shapeData)) {
  if(shapeData@data[i,]$TOTAL2011 > 400){

    m <- addPolygons(m, data=shapeData[i,],weight=1, popup = map_popup2, fillOpacity = 0.5,
                     color = "yellow") %>%
    print(m)

 }
}
```

Comment: You could just subset your data to a new object first and avoid the iteration entirely. shapeData.sub <- shapeData[shapeData$TOTAL2011 < 400,]

Comment: @JeffreyEvans Ok i'll just use subset, its less hassle than iteration and is much more efficient, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Jeffery Evans answer shown above in the comments. In his answer he suggested I subset my data :

```
shapeData.sub <- shapeData[shapeData$TOTAL2011 < 400,]
```

This worked perfectly.